# The clicked item should be in center in owl carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

```
$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
    margin:10,
    dots:false,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
});
```

The Above is my Owl carousel. Now i need clicked owl-item should be center. please any me

Comment: please provide more code/brief and provide a working example.

Answer (score 11):

1. You can trigger [the `to.owl.carousel` event](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#to-owl-carousel) when the user clicks on the item. This event causes the Owl Carousel to move to a specific position.
2. I've set the `data-position` attribute for each `div` inside the carousel before initializing the carousel. Then I use this attribute as a parameter of the `to.owl.carousel` event.

Please check the result: https://codepen.io/glebkema/details/dWXzza/

```js
var $owl = $('.owl-carousel');

$owl.children().each( function( index ) {
  $(this).attr( 'data-position', index ); // NB: .attr() instead of .data()
});

$owl.owlCarousel({
  center: true,
  loop: true,
  items: 5,
});

$(document).on('click', '.owl-item>div', function() {
  $owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', $(this).data( 'position' ) ); 
});
```

```css
.owl-item > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 9px 12px;
  transition: margin 0.4s ease;
}
.owl-item.center > div {
  cursor: auto;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="owl-carousel">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/f06/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/f63/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/fc3/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/693/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/3cc/fff/?text=5" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/369/fff/?text=6" alt=""></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x300/936/fff/?text=7" alt=""></div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Crock I've added two items and fixed my solution. Please check.

Comment: I have a plugin initializing the owl carousel, could I add the lines of code that add the data-id attribute after the initialization and still expect the same result?

Comment: @Burkely91 After initialization, the structure of the  HTML blocks becomes more complex. Test it with developer tools in a browser and compare it to the one my code generates. If the correct blocks receive the correct attributes, then the event handler will work well.